# Cannot insert data with thread

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I want to insert data through threads into my MySQL-database. In order to get my data I need to parse multiple XML files, so I decided to let each file be parsed by one thread.

If I run the code to insert it without threads everything works fine, but if I run the same code with more threads a windows error pops up and the program quits.

```
#semaphore.acquire()
try:
    cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" %
                   (filename, tablename))
    commit()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    pass
#semaphore.release()
```

That's the function I am calling through a thread. I commented out the semaphore since I am testing this code with only 1 thread (which should be the same result as not using any thread at all, but the program still shuts down)

Here is my errorcode:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Why can I not run this code with a single thread?

EDIT:
Thats how I call my function:

```
 def start_thread():  
        t = Thread(target=thread_parse, args=(file_name,))
        t.start()
        thread_list.append(t)

        for t in thread_list:
            t.join()

def thread_parse(file_name):
    parser = CVEParser()
    parser.parse(file_name) # Thats the function where it crashes
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: I edited my original post

Comment: Does "load data local infile" not support threads?

Comment: Is CVEParser your own class? What's it doing inside the parse call? The 0xc0000005 error is an access violation error. Nothing is jumping out at me as to what would be causing it from the code you've posted

Comment: yes its my own class, this class parses a XML file and saves the data into a txt, which is then loaded with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. But if I run the same code without a thread it works, and as soon as I use 1 thread it crashes.

Comment: anyway this is a futile excercise because LOAD DATA takes a lock on the table and other threads wouldn't be able to do LOAD DATA concurrently.

Comment: but since I am using only 1 thread at the moment, there shouldn't be other threads doing anything with the table

Comment: I'm having a pretty similar issue.  Got it to a point where one thread could print, sleep(1), and print again and the second print never appeared.  Don't have a small repro handy, but it seemed to depend on which underlying mysql/mariahdb client i had.  I switched to multiprocessing and it worked... but very strange...